# How to show conditional tab in webform 7.x-3.x

Tags: 7, webforms, entities

I created an enquiry form using the webform 7.x-3.x module and I want to create condition on field, but not showing conditionals tab.

[image]

I also use webform_conditional 7.x-1.0-beta2 but conditional tab not  showing.

But,
I create again enquiry form from webform 7.x-4.x Module. In webform i show conditionals tabs.
[image]

My question is how to show conditions tabs in webform 7.x-3.x. I not want to upgrade module webform 3.x to 4.x.

Have any configuration or module to show conditional tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to use this within webform you need to use [webform conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) to work smoothly.